Will a cat run away if you lock it out the house for a night or two?
We have two cats (males, both neutered) who, inexplicably starting pooing in the house in the last week. (We're not sure if it's one or both of them).
I cannot think what could have caused this sudden new behavior. (We have two mid-size dogs who sleep outside at night. I doubt that's their reason for not wanting to go outside; they all get along perfectly fine).
Being out of ideas on how to deal with the cats pooing in the house, I suggested to my wife that we should lock them out for a night or two to force them to do their business in the garden (which is what they usually do), but her concern is that they might run away. Is that a reasonable concern?

if your cat is used to be outside there is no reason to think it will run away,but your cat will not understand why it is locked out so it is unlikely to change the behaviour.

Breaking litter box (or garden) protocol should always call for a visit to the vet. This may be explicable as an expression of discomfort, or confusion.
